# New Bower packages added don't show up in solution until close/open

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, bower

Not sure if there's anything I can do to get a slightly better workflow going in VS2015 for .netcore or not, so thought I'd ask.

When adding new bower packages to my .netcore solution, let's use Durandal as an example.

Original bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "bootswatch": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "~3.2.6",
    "angular": "1.5.7",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.7"
  }
}
```

Updated with Durandal:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "bootswatch": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "~3.2.6",
    "angular": "1.5.7",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.7",
    "durandal": "~2.1.0"
  }
}
```

now my packages install correctly, but in my `wwwroot/lib/...` I cannot actually see the packages that were just installed through the change in my bower.json.  If i go to the directory directly in explorer, i can see that durandal, require, and knockout were installed - they just aren't showing up in my solution, and I cannot reference them in my solution until I close and reopen the solution.

I believe in previous versions of the framework, there was a "refresh" button either at the top of the solution, or on the right click of an object like a folder.  This no longer seems to be the case.

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing?  It's a minor inconvenience as there is a workaround, but still I'd prefer not to do it if anyone has any idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new Bower dependency, VS automatically asks Bower to get it. Bower requires some time to complete the operation. For example, to get Ember.js, I needed to wait about 4 mins until Bower completed.

But if, by any reason, you do not see the package in wwwroot\lib folder you can reload the packages again. Try this:

[image]